# php::array_diff() to non-scalar, like objects

Tags: php, arrays, diff

I need get a diff between two objects arrays, but [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) compare array elements like `(string) $value1 === (string) $value2`, it causes a cast fail like `Warning: Uncaught Object of class YourClass could not be converted to string`.

Basically I have two arrays, like:

```
<?php

// Simulating objects:
$value1 = (object) [ "value" => 1 ];
$value2 = (object) [ "value" => 2 ];
$value3 = (object) [ "value" => 3 ];

// Arrays:
$array1 = [ $value1, $value2 ];
$array2 = [ $value2, $value3 ];

// Difference:
$arrayDifference = array_diff($array1, $array2);

// Expected:
$arrayDifference = [ $array1 ];

// What happen:
// Warning: Uncaught Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

I just need check if `$object1 == $object2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
   <?php

    function array_difference($array1,$array2){
         $result=array();
         foreach($array1 as $a1){
             if(!in_array($a1,$array2)){
                 array_push($result,$a1);
             }
         }
         return $result;
     }
    // Simulating objects:
    $value1 = (object) [ "value" => 1 ];
    $value2 = (object) [ "value" => 2 ];
    $value3 = (object) [ "value" => 3 ];

    // Arrays:
    $array1 = [ $value1, $value2 ];
    $array2 = [ $value2, $value3 ];

    $arrayDifference=array_difference($array1,$array2);
    var_dump($arrayDifference);
```

Output will be

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'value' => int 1
```